# Rails keeps on asking me to "Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Everything was working fine, then all of a sudden I was not able to run "rails s" or "rails c" anymore.

I keep getting the following error msg:

```
The git source https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git is not yet checked out.
Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
```

I have searched online and they said to run: `spring binstubs --all`, but this does not work and gives me the same error message as above.

Please help. Last thing I did was push a code to heroku and github. Rails server, console was working fine then this happens.

I have tried running bundle install, it outputs this error

```
...
Resolving dependencies...............
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 5.0.4)

  In Gemfile:
    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.11.0, which depends on
      railties (< 6.1, >= 5.2)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.4, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.4)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Take note that I did not do any changes to anything, that's why its so weird. It was working 5minutes earlier then all of a sudden this occurs.
I have restarted my Mac already and issue still persists

Comment: To address the elephant in the room... have you run bundle install? What output do you get when you do?

Comment: Hi @Mark I have updated the question with the output from bundle install.
I am now in the process of reinstalling ruby using rbenv, reinstalling bundler, and rerunning bundle install to be sure

Comment: Have you run bundle update? Btw, if you are using rvm, please check your username you are currently using

Comment: If bundle update doesn't work, it's sometimes worth deleting your `Gemfile.lock`, and trying `bundle install` again

Comment: I have not yet run bundle update. Im actually not expecting any new gems/updates thats why I did not run it. Is that wrong thinking? I will try next

Comment: @HùngNguyễn I am using rbenv

Comment: As per an answer below it seems tied to inerhited_ressourced gem which is a dependency of Active Admin. Your version of Active Admin require a version of inherited_ressourced that require a version of Railties that conflict with Rails. Try removing the version of Active admin, and do `bundle update activeadmin` if it doesn't work please copy your gemfile in your question

Answer (score 3):

From the stacktrace, I see the issue to be with the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources) gem. If you look at the [gemspec](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/master/inherited_resources.gemspec#L25) of this gem for v1.11.0 which you are currently using, you can see where it explicitly states >= 5.2 for railties. However, it appears you running rails 5.0.0 which is tied into 5.0.4 of railties.

To fix this, I suggest fixing the `inherited_resources` gem to [v1.9.0](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/v1.9.0/inherited_resources.gemspec) which can use railties 5.0.4 and then re-run `bundle install`

```
gem inherited_resources, "1.9.0"
```

Comment: Inherited_resources seems more like a dependency than a proper gem, it looks tied to ActiveAdmin. Removing version of `gem activeadmin` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix just by simply uninstall and reinstalling my ruby and running bundle install

```
rbenv uninstall  
rbenv install  
gem install bundler  
bundle install  
rails s
```